# Trying to implement a delegate that signals when the back button is pressed in the navigation bar - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, delegates

I have a main list of articles, and upon clicking one it segues to a reading view controller, and there I keep track of the progress of the user's reading with that view controller having an NSNumber property holding the position. I want to update this position back to the root view controller when they press the back button (so I can show them their progress) but my delegate doesn't seem to be working.

In the reading view's .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<UpdateProgressDelegate> delegate;

...

@protocol UpdateProgressDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)finishedReadingWithPosition:(NSNumber *)position;

@end
```

In the .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishedReading:)]) {
        [self.delegate finishedReadingWithPosition:self.position];
    }
}
```

In my root view (note it does indeed implement the protocol):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ReadBasicArticleSegue"] || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ReadFullArticleSegue"]) {
        ReadingViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        self.rowOfLastSelectedCell = @(indexPath.row);
        Article *article = self.articles[[self.rowOfLastSelectedCell intValue]];

        // Set ReadingViewController's variables so the selected article can be read
        destination.textToRead = [article.body componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        destination.wordsPerMinute = @(1500);
        destination.numberOfWordsShown = @(3);

        destination.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

and...

```
- (void)finishedReadingWithPosition:(NSNumber *)position {
    Article *article = [self.articles objectAtIndex:[self.rowOfLastSelectedCell intValue]];
    article.position = position;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I just don't see what I'm doing wrong. When I press the back button, the root view controller still has a 0% progress indicator.

Comment: Have you specified that your root view should implement the delegate methods in the root view's .h file? Like this:

@interface RootViewControllerClass : SuperClass <UpdateProgressDelegate>

Comment: What if you try calling `[super viewWillDisappear:YES];` after the delegate call?

Comment: The first thing you should do (always with delegate troubleshooting) is put a log inside finishedReadingWithPosition: to see if it's called.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishedReading:)]) {
        [self.delegate finishedReadingWithPosition:self.position];
    }
}
```

- `viewDidDisappear:` should pass the same 'did' method to `super`, not `viewWillDisappear:` ..
  `[super viewDidDisappear:animated];`
- The selector `finishedReading:` is not the same as the selector `finishedReadingWithPosition:`. As it is not implemented in the delegate, the conditional is not called.

Typos - or the solution...?

Comment: two things, log out self.position and make sure its not nil,

Answer (score 0):

two quick things:

first, in your delegate respondstoSelector check, make sure you are testing for the correct method.  You have "finishedReading:" in the check, then you call finishedREadingWithPosition:" in the method call.  My guess is that it's skipping that line because its the wrong selector your checking for.

next make sure self.position have a value
and also:
I agree on the [super] call that @He Was mentioned - needs to be a call for the same method